# Profiling blackberry application. GraphicsInternal.updateDisplayFromBackBuffer0(...) drains battery a lot

Tags: blackberry, java-me, profiling

I'm currently profiling a blackberry application, to know where part of the application drains battery. In one of my `MainScreen`, I noticed that when I push this screen the **CPU Utilization** increases upto **100%**, then I saw that the method `GraphicsInternal.updateDisplayFromBackBuffer(...)` method uses upto **70%** of the CPU. Now my question is, why is it that this method consumes that amount of resources?

Comment: It's difficult to say without reading the code. Perhaps you have coded a loop to periodically update the screen?

Comment: check these links: [the first](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/General-BlackBerry-Functions-and/10-Top-Blackberry-Battery-Saving-Tips/td-p/1688603) and [the second](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/03/battery-drain-apps/)

Comment: @Mister Smith thank you. Yeah it seems that my app runs in an infinite loop. Just found it, in my BitmapField I override the paint() and inside my paint() method I have super.setBitmap(). Base on the api docs, setBitmap() marks the field as invalid which cause the screen to repaint. http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BitmapField.html#setBitmap(net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap)